# Exchange 2010 - Remove a mailbox and add a new one

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email-bounces

I am experiencing the issue of walking into a new company as a sysadmin and no one has looked after their exchange for a long time.

Because of that there is a mailbox (Lets call it Mailer) that is around 1TB now and gets around 9000 e-mails a day.

It is the only mailbox in a database (edb) but due to its size I am struggling to do anything with it.

I have tried PowerShell export to PST commands *(New-MailboxExportRequest)*, even running it in a months cut off it takes up to 5 days to run (Running PowerShell on a local PC as when I did it in the Exchange server it became unresponsive)

While the Export command is running, we are getting a heap of "E-mail delayed" notifications coming out of that account to customers (Really bad thing).

So my new theory is, create a new mail database, in that create a new mailbox. Then somehow tell my mail account (Lets call it Mailer) to use that mailbox instead of the huge one.

The only issue is I have no idea how to achieve this, or if it is even possible. Any help would be great.

Comment: `It is the only mailbox in a database (edb) but due to its size I am struggling to do anything with it.` - You've said that you've tried to export the mailbox to a pst file and that that's not working, but it isn't clear exactly what you're trying to do with the mailbox. Are you trying to reduce the size of it?

Comment: Hey @joeqwerty, currently the mailbox is pretty unresponsive due to its size and the hdd that its sitting on is quickly running out of space. So what I am trying to do is get it to a point where the mailbox is useful.

Comment: Any reason you can't just rename the account and make a new one with the old name?

Comment: I had considered doing that but was worried about unknown ramifications

Comment: Erase the account and recreate it ?